# Export and import for Google Inbox's saved link feature?

Tags: gmail

Google Inbox has this great link saving feature that lets you save a link from an extension, the mobile app, or the Google Inbox itself. I really like how you can snooze links for later. I have a ton of links saved through this. Unfortunately, Google Inbox is going away at the end of March 2019.

Gmail does not show any of these previously saved links. Does anyone have a good way to export these links. They don't seem to be listed in takeout. As a bonus, what would you import them into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export 'Save to inbox' links from Inbox mail:

Create an Archive of 'Reminders' on [takeout.google.com](https://takeout.google.com)
because all your 'Save to inbox' links are stored in 'Reminders'
You will get a zip file of your links to download.

But I don't know how to import them into Gmail. Any idea?

Comment: That exported them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the "Reminder" Folder in Gmail on takeout.google.com so I used the following strategie:

1. left panel choose "Saved"
2. scroll down until all relevent saved items are visible on the page
3. open browser console
4. run this script to get all links

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('qH')).concat(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('pC'))).map((el) => {const href=el.parentNode.href; const pos1 = href.indexOf('www.google.com/url?q='); if (pos1!==-1){const pos2=href.indexOf('&');return decodeURIComponent(href.substring(pos1 +'www.google.com/url?q='.length, (pos2===-1?href.length:pos2)))} else {return href}}).join("\r")
```

The script is searching the open page for all "VIEW"-buttons and will extract the urls. Additional it will unpack all urls which would need a redirect thru google.

if you miss links ensure that you scrolled until all your saved links have been visible.

Comment: Nice idea to grab the links directly from the page. Searching for className 'pC' missed some of my saved links (all the ones without pictures). To find all, you can look for the link itself: `'[href*="//www.google.com/url?"]'`. Here's a version that found all my links: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[href*="//www.google.com/url?"]')).map(el => decodeURIComponent(el.search.replace(/.*q=([^&]+).*/, '$1'))).join('\n')`

Comment: you are absolute right - I missed the links without an Image but I do have many links not starting with "www.google.com/url". I changed my answer to include the other links by searching for both classes